# Ruby element in URL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, erb

I'm trying to include @user.username as part of some URLs

```
<%= image_tag("https://twitter.com/api/users/profile_image?screen_name=<%= @user.username %>") %>
```

in order to display the twitter avatar from a certain user. I have tried with:

```
  <%= image_tag("https://twitter.com/api/users/profile_image?screen_name=").join(<%= @user.username %>) %>
```

but both return a non correctly render.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [interpolation](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Ruby_Programming/Syntax/Literals#Interpolation) since it's already a string in Ruby, e.g.:

```
<%= image_tag("https://twitter.com/api/users/profile_image?screen_name=#{@user.username}") %>
```